# How to replace HDD for SDD on Ubuntu 20.04 using software-based RAID 1

Tags: 20.04, hard-drive, raid

I have a Dell PowerEdge R210 II with two 500GB 7200rpm HDD's setup with software-based RAID 1.   I'd like to replace them with two Samsung SDD's.    What is the simplest way to do this without a total replacement and reinstall of the OS and apps?

Note:  the poweredge R210 came with PERC for RAID but it is disabled.

I'm assuming I can't just shutdown, pull one of the HDD's, replace it with an SDD, let it replicate and then do the same with the other (though that would be nice!)

Comment: "I'm assuming I can't just shutdown, pull one of the HDD's, replace it with an SDD, let it replicate and then do the same with the other (though that would be nice!)"
Why not? :) That would be my 1st attempt if I was the one doing this

Comment: @Rinzwind How would i go about that? this isn't in production use so it can have downtime. Is it as simple as powering down, swapping out one of the HDD's for an SDD, rebooting and formatting the SDD? If so, what command line tools are used to format and get Ubuntu RAID to 'see' the new drive and begin syncing?